# IBM MQ - Java api - PCFMessageAgent - connection fails

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I changed the MQIVP sample in MQ with a server connection channel of my own  **local.server.con** and it is working fine. But I tried connecting to the same channel with **PCFMessageAgent** and the connection is failing with errors in MQ log. What is the relation between my channel and **SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE** which gives the error.

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\Tools\wmqjava\samples>java -Djava.library.path="C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\java\lib" MQIVPMod
Websphere MQ for Java Installation Verification Program
5724-B4 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2002, 2014. All Rights Reserved.
================================================================

Please enter the IP address of the MQ server                  :10.40.1.16
Please enter the port to connect to                           : (1414)1415
Please enter the server connection channel name               :local.server.con
Please enter the user name (or RETURN for none)               :test
Please enter the password for the user                        :test123
Please enter the queue manager name                           :local
Success: Connected to queue manager.
Success: Opened SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LOCAL.QUEUE
Success: Put a message to SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LOCAL.QUEUE
Success: Got a message from SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LOCAL.QUEUE
Success: Closed SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LOCAL.QUEUE
Success: Disconnected from queue manager


Tests complete -
SUCCESS: This MQ Transport is functioning correctly.
Press Enter to continue ...
```

My PCFMessageAgent code and error:

```
new PCFMessageAgent(host, Integer.parseInt(port), channelName); // connect

com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2035'.
    at com.ibm.mq.MQDestination.open(MQDestination.java:323)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueue.<init>(MQQueue.java:236)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.accessQueue(MQQueueManager.java:2674)
    at com.ibm.mq.pcf.PCFAgent.open(PCFAgent.java:448)
    at com.ibm.mq.pcf.PCFAgent.open(PCFAgent.java:394)
    at com.ibm.mq.pcf.PCFAgent.connect(PCFAgent.java:287)
    at com.ibm.mq.pcf.PCFAgent.<init>(PCFAgent.java:190)
    at com.ibm.mq.pcf.PCFMessageAgent.<init>(PCFMessageAgent.java:157)
    at test.wmq.PCFTest.main(PCFTest.java:49)
```

And the MQ log :

```
5/2/2017 14:01:31 - Process(6048.60) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqzlaa0.exe)
                      Host(BLR_SWG_N09505) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(8.0.0.4) QMgr(local)

AMQ8077: Entity 'test@blr_swg_n09505' has insufficient authority to access
object 'SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE'.

EXPLANATION:
The specified entity is not authorized to access the required object. The
following requested permissions are unauthorized: get
ACTION:
Ensure that the correct level of authority has been set for this entity against
the required object, or ensure that the entity is a member of a privileged
group. 
----- amqzfubn.c : 518 --------------------------------------------------------
5/2/2017 14:01:32 - Process(8004.41) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqrmppa.exe)
                      Host(BLR_SWG_N09505) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(8.0.0.4) QMgr(local)

AMQ9208: Error on receive from host BLR_SWG_N09505 (10.40.1.16).

EXPLANATION:
An error occurred receiving data from BLR_SWG_N09505 (10.40.1.16) over TCP/IP.
This may be due to a communications failure.
ACTION:
The return code from the TCP/IP recv() call was 10054 (X'2746'). Record these
values and tell the systems administrator. 
----- amqccita.c : 4076 -------------------------------------------------------
5/2/2017 14:01:32 - Process(8004.41) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqrmppa.exe)
                      Host(BLR_SWG_N09505) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(8.0.0.4) QMgr(local)

AMQ9999: Channel 'local.server.con' to host '10.40.1.16' ended abnormally.

EXPLANATION:
The channel program running under process ID 8004(7988) for channel
'local.server.con' ended abnormally. The host name is '10.40.1.16'; in some
cases the host name cannot be determined and so is shown as '????'.
ACTION:
Look at previous error messages for the channel program in the error logs to
determine the cause of the failure. Note that this message can be excluded
completely or suppressed by tuning the "ExcludeMessage" or "SuppressMessage"
attributes under the "QMErrorLog" stanza in qm.ini. Further information can be
found in the System Administration Guide. 
----- amqrmrsa.c : 930 --------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go and read up on MQ permissions (i.e. authorizations).  It is best to do permissions on the group rather than principle (UserId).

```
setmqaut -m {QM_NAME} -n SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.QUEUE -t queue -g {GROUP} +put +inq +dsp
setmqaut -m {QM_NAME} -n SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE -t queue -g {GROUP} +get +inq +dsp
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no relation between channels and model queues.

But I think, that the PCFMessageAgent is trying to create a dynamic queue to use as a ReplyToQ to receive responses, and it seems it tries to create the dynamic queue by opening the SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE.

Comment: Any sample code/Doc for PCFMessageAgent on channels?